# Receiving jsonp response in PHP only

Tags: php

I have the following jsonp response:

```
var foo= '',
callback = functionName;
(
    function() {
        var arr = eval('[' + decodeURIComponent(foo) + ']');
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            arr = arr[0];
        } else 
            arr={};
        callback(arr);
    }
)();
```

Normally when I get this as a script tag's response the callback function is invoked from a self-invoking closure and I get the proper parameters.

But what if I wanted to do this in PHP?

I am passing function's name as a get parameter, so in PHP I pass anything in order to get the string response. I use cURL to get the string like at the top of this post, and I now should get the array of response variables.

But how do I get this, if I can't parse it with javascript?

Is this the correct approach to do this?